# How to click on the button within linkedin profile using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

a very quick question. I want use selenium to click on a button in my LinkedIN profile in order to expand an area. Unfortunately I am always running in errors. In the following the button that I am trying to click:

```
<button class="pv-profile-section__see-more-inline pv-profile-section__text-truncate-toggle link link-without-hover-state" aria-expanded="false" type="button">Mehr anzeigen
<li-icon aria-hidden="true" type="chevron-down-icon" class="pv-profile-section__toggle-detail-icon" size="small"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16" data-supported-dps="16x16" fill="currentColor" width="16" height="16" focusable="false">
  <path d="M8 9l5.93-4L15 6.54l-6.15 4.2a1.5 1.5 0 01-1.69 0L1 6.54 2.07 5z"></path>
</svg></li-icon></button>
```

So far, that`s what I have been trying:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("pv-profile-section__actions-inline ember-view")
```

Unfortuntately that didn´t work. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: What errors do you get?

Answer (score 1):

The desired element is a dynamic element, so to click on the element you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.pv-profile-section__see-more-inline.pv-profile-section__text-truncate-toggle.link.link-without-hover-state"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='pv-profile-section__see-more-inline pv-profile-section__text-truncate-toggle link link-without-hover-state' and contains(., 'Mehr anzeigen')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

More canonically, you can use:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.pv-profile-section__see-more-inline.pv-profile-section__text-truncate-toggle.link.link-without-hover-state li-icon.pv-profile-section__toggle-detail-icon"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='pv-profile-section__see-more-inline pv-profile-section__text-truncate-toggle link link-without-hover-state' and contains(., 'Mehr anzeigen')]//li-icon[@class='pv-profile-section__toggle-detail-icon']"))).click()
  ```